# Tomes: how can I use them?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

"Duh, you just read them." I certainly suppose so, but how? where? Right clicking on them does nothing. The DoD wiki does have [an article on them](http://www.dredmorwiki.com/wiki/Tomes), but it merely lists the possible tomes, without explaining how to "activate" them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tomes are merely off-hand weapons that you can use for additional stats.
So to 'activate' them, you simply equip them in your off-hand slot and you will gain whatever additional stats they have.

Eg: The "Little Black Book" will give you 2 additional Necromantic damage and 1 Necromantic damage resistance. Plus any additional stats should it have more enchantments.